# Wordpress API get all posts

Tags: json, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

i am trying to get all posts ( only their link ) with wp-json. I have around 40 posts currently.

this request works partially...it gives me around 8 posts back but not all.

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields=link
```

when I add all categories to the request I get every post

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields=link&per_page=100&page=1&categories=1,2,3,6,7,8,21
```

this solution is not the best since I ll add categories in the future.

what is wrong with my first request ??

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the filter to change the parameters.

```
add_action( 'rest_movies_params', function( $params ){
    if ( isset( $params ) AND isset( $params[ 'per_page' ] ) ) {
        $params[ 'per_page' ][ 'maximum' ] = 200;
    }
    return $params;
});
```

Here I have shared the link for official code reference.
[Link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_collection_params/)

And in fetch url add `?per_page=200`

Here I have shared the example of url:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/movies?per_page=200
```

Notes:

1. Currently in my example (code and url) I have added movies custom post type for reference. you can change according to your requirement.
2. If posts is greter then 200 then you can use the `?page=2` in your url.

Answer (score 0):

Use per_page.

Search takes per_page
/wp-json/wp/v2/search?per_page=40

See https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/search-results/

Posts will get that many plus revisions. per_page should work though. If refreshing in the browser make sure to clear cache each time/
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=3

See https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/

Comment: hmm strange this is not working for me.    /wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields=link&per_page=100. gets me now 16 results. but not all.